Reorder "ragged" numpy array defined by offsets (i.e. contiguous slices)
I have a long 1D numeric data array of bytes (e.g. chars) along with a set of offsets which define a set of contiguous slices along the array (e.g. these could correspond to words). Here's an example, showing the character equivalent of each byte:
data = np.array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!'])
offsets = np.array([0, 5, 10, 13, 14]) # defines words [0:5], [5:10], [10:13], [13:14]

I want an efficient way to rearrange the slices ("words") in the original array to make a new reordered data array. For instance,
new_word_order = np.array([2, 1, 0, 3])  # length == len(offset)-1
# some function that uses the new_word_order to make the following
new_data == np.array(['y', 'o', 'u', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!'])
new_offsets == np.array([0, 3, 8, 13, 14])

Ideally, I would also like the function to be able to duplicate or delete indexes:
new_word_order = np.array([2, 3, 3, 2, 3])  # no longer needs to be the same length as `offsets`
# results in
new_data == np.array(['y', 'o', 'u', '!', '!', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!'])
new_offsets = np.array([0, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9])

EDIT: I have concocted the solution below which uses np.arange repeatedly inside a list comprehension
ranges = np.array([offsets[:-1], offsets[1:]]).T
reordered_ranges = ranges[new_word_order, :]
new_offsets = np.zeros(len(new_word_order)+1, dtype=offsets.dtype)
idx = [np.arange(l, r, dtype=offsets.dtype) for l, r in reordered_ranges if l != r]
select = [] if len(idx) == 0 else np.concatenate(idx)
new_data = data[select]
new_offsets = np.insert(np.cumsum(np.diff(reordered_ranges, axis=1)), 0, 0)

But I worry that for large arrays (say a million slices) this will be inefficient, so I'me wondering if there's a build-in multiple-slice accessor, or if something with np.r_, np.s_, or np.slice would avoid the need for large numbers of np.arange calls. The answer at Convert list of tuples into list of slices to use with np.r_ seems to suggest maybe not.

Working code, even if it isn't "efficient" would be nice.  My gut feeling is that this isn't a common task, so there's unlikely to be any special numpy code.  It seems to me just a matter of calculating new offsets.  Actually applying the offsets to make 'words' is just a matter of iteratively making slices of different lengths.  But that splitting isn't integral to calculating new offsets.  I think you just have to work out the details.

Thanks. I've now concocted a solution using a list comprehension and repeated calls to np.arange, but I worry that repeated calls to arrange like this might be inefficient for large arrays. Apologies for the single liner here: ranges = np.array([offsets[:-1], offsets[1:]]).T; reordered_ranges = ranges[new_word_order, :]; new_offsets = np.zeros(len(new_word_order)+1, dtype=offsets.dtype); new_offsets[1:] = np.cumsum(np.diff(reordered_ranges, axis=1)); new_data = data[np.hstack([np.arange(l, r,  dtype=np.uint64) for l, r in reordered_ranges if l != r])]

can you edit the question itself?  formatting will bw better

Done, and clarified concerns about multiple np.arange calls. Thanks!

Examining how split works suggests how to do the reorder.
In [537]: data = np.array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'y', 'o', 'u', '!'])
     ...: offsets = np.array([0, 5, 10, 13, 14]) #

In [538]: np.split(data, offsets)
Out[538]: 
[array([], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['t', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['y', 'o', 'u'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['!'], dtype='<U1'),
 array([], dtype='<U1')]

And after the change:
In [539]: new_word_order = np.array([2, 1, 0, 3])  # length == len(offset)-1
     ...: # some function that uses the new_word_order to make the following
     ...: new_data = np.array(['y', 'o', 'u', 't', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '!'])
     ...: new_offsets = np.array([0, 3, 8, 13, 14])

In [540]: np.split(new_data, new_offsets)
Out[540]: 
[array([], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['y', 'o', 'u'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['t', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['!'], dtype='<U1'),
 array([], dtype='<U1')]

Given a list of offsets, split essentially does:
In [544]: [data[s:e] for s,e in zip([0,0,5,10,13,14],[0,5,10,13,14,14])]
Out[544]: 
[array([], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['t', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['y', 'o', 'u'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['!'], dtype='<U1'),
 array([], dtype='<U1')]

It does require contiguous data.
That list comprehension suggests that I could just reorder the start/end indices:
In [549]: idx = np.array([[0,0,5,10,13,14],[0,5,10,13,14,14]]); idx
Out[549]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  5, 10, 13, 14],
       [ 0,  5, 10, 13, 14, 14]])

In [550]: newidx=idx[:,[0,3,2,1,4]]; newidx
Out[550]: 
array([[ 0, 10,  5,  0, 13],
       [ 0, 13, 10,  5, 14]])

In [551]: [data[s:e] for s,e in zip(*newidx)]
Out[551]: 
[array([], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['y', 'o', 'u'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['t', 'h', 'e', 'r', 'e'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['!'], dtype='<U1')]

And the reordering can contain duplicates or omissions:
In [552]: newidx=idx[:,[0, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4]]; newidx
Out[552]: 
array([[ 0, 10, 13, 13, 10, 13],
       [ 0, 13, 14, 14, 13, 14]])

In [553]: [data[s:e] for s,e in zip(*newidx)]
Out[553]: 
[array([], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['y', 'o', 'u'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['!'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['!'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['y', 'o', 'u'], dtype='<U1'),
 array(['!'], dtype='<U1')]

I'm nust taking your reorder list, adding 1, and passing with 0 etc to match split behavior.
